# Saving an instance of a constantly changing variable

Tags: java

I've got a float variable called angleOfGun which is containing the angle of the gun on the screen, which is constantly moving. I want to save the angle that the gun was at when the user clicks the screen in a separate float variable, currentAngle. The problem is, currentAngle keeps updating with angleOfGun because angleOfGun is changing..

Do you have any ideas of how I could save an instance of angleOfGun into currentAngle without currentAngle updating any more after the initial value is set? Thanks!

```
    float angleOfGun = 1;

    //boolean for direction of rotation
    boolean clockwise = false;

 /**
 * Action to perform on clock tick
 * 
 * @param g the canvas object on which to draw
 */
public void tick(Canvas g) {

    int height = g.getHeight();
    int width = g.getWidth();

    //rotate/draw the gun
    g.save();
    g.rotate(angleOfGun, width - 5, 5);
    g.drawRect(new RectF(width - 40, 0, width, 60), bluePaint);
    g.restore();

    if(ballPosition != null)
    {
        float currentAngle = angleOfGun;
        g.save();
        g.rotate(currentAngle, width - 5, 5);
        ballPosition.x = ballPosition.x - ballVelocity.x;
        ballPosition.y = ballPosition.y - ballVelocity.y;
        g.drawCircle(ballPosition.x, ballPosition.y, 10, greenPaint);
        g.restore();
    }

    if(clockwise)
    {
        angleOfGun = (angleOfGun - 1) % 360;
        if(angleOfGun == 0)
        {
            clockwise = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        angleOfGun = (angleOfGun + 1) % 360;
        if(angleOfGun == 90)
        {
            clockwise = true;
        }
    }


}


 /**
 * callback method, run when when surface is touched
 */
public void onTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    if(ballPosition == null && shoot == false)
    {
        shoot = true;
        ballPosition = new PointF(0,0);
        ballVelocity = new PointF(0,0);
        ballPosition.x = 1280;
        ballPosition.y = 0;
        ballVelocity.x = 0;
        ballVelocity.y = -5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Click Handler you can show us? It'll likely tie in there, instead of in tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class you have method `tick()` there is line in the code:

```
float currentAngle = angleOfGun;
```

So you constantly assign value of `angleOfGun` to `currentAngle`. So after this declaration in your code  you simply can use `currentAngle`in place of `angleOfGun` in your code(and vice versa) and this will have no effect on anything, as **they both store same value**. 
Don't forget that Java is OOP language, so you can take advantage of that. My approach would be to create class called `Angle`where i can have `private static float currentAngle` field and `private float gunAngle`. By creating mutators, value of this variables could be manipulated to satisfy any need. This approach will help by simplifying code and would give you flexibility to make further changes by adding or removing methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would create another variable gunLocked (boolean). When you set the gun angle just lock it, and test to see if it is locked. If it is don't update, otherwise do.

```
if(ballPosition != null)
{
    if (!gunLocked)
    {
        float currentAngle = angleOfGun;

        gunLocked = true;

        g.save();
        g.rotate(currentAngle, width - 5, 5);
        ballPosition.x = ballPosition.x - ballVelocity.x;
        ballPosition.y = ballPosition.y - ballVelocity.y;
        g.drawCircle(ballPosition.x, ballPosition.y, 10, greenPaint);
        g.restore();
    }
}
```

Of course this does mean that you'll have to create another way to unlock the gun (on a button press maybe? such as when the user moved the gun)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using primitive types ideally it should not happen. Try this:

```
declare currentAngle also globally like angleOfGun
```

Comment: I do not understand this. Looks like another programming language

Comment: global variables are evil.

Comment: @Karunakar  There is no such thing as global variables in java. But you can make variables Globally accessible while their class is loaded by using `static` keyword.